# Angular Undefined path?

Tags: angular, rest, api, get, undefined

In my Angular application, I've a delete method for every customer of a list:

In the customers resource component:

```
delete2(id: string) {
        this.customerService.delete2(id);
        this.synchronize();
    }
```

In the customers resource view:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let item;">
<button mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="delete(item.id)">
                    <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
                  </button>
```

In the customer service:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
    static END_POINT = '/customers';

constructor(private httpService: HttpService, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    }

readAll(): Observable<Customer[]> {
        return this.httpService.get(CustomerService.END_POINT);
    }

delete2(id: string) {
        this.httpService.delete(CustomerService.END_POINT + '/' + id).subscribe(
            () => { this.readAll();
                this.successful();
            }
        );
    }
```

And finally, the HttpService used by  the Customer Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    static API_END_POINT = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v0';

    private params: URLSearchParams;

    private headers: Headers;

    private responseType: ResponseContentType;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.params = new URLSearchParams();
        this.headers = new Headers();
    }

    param(key: string, value: string): HttpService {
        this.params.append(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    header(key: string, value: string): HttpService {
        this.headers.append(key, value);
        return this;
    }

get(endpoint: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(HttpService.API_END_POINT + endpoint, this.createOptions()).map(
            response => this.extractData(response)).catch(
                error => {
                    return this.handleError(error);
                });
    }

delete(endpoint: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.delete(HttpService.API_END_POINT + endpoint, this.createOptions()).map(
            response => this.extractData(response)).catch(
                error => {
                    return this.handleError(error);
                });
    }

private createOptions(): RequestOptions {
        const options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, params: this.params });
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.params = new URLSearchParams();
        return options;
    }

    private extractData(res: Response): any {
        if (res.text()) {
            if (res.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('application/json') !== -1) {
                return res.json();
            } else {
                return res.text();
            }
        } else {
            return res;
        }
    }
```

But when I try to dele an existing customer, I get the next error:

GET http://localhost:8080/api/v0/customers/undefined 404 ()

**undefined, path:/api/v0/customers/undefined**

Although I've reviewed the code, I don't understand where the "undefined" error is, since I send the "id" and I've no back-end problem with creating new customers.

**Update**:

I've corrected the error and it deletes the customer, but now I try to do it through a confirmation cancel/yes dialog.

So, in the resource component, my delete2() method has changed to:

```
delete2(customer: Customer) {
        this.customerService.readObservable(customer.id).subscribe(
            data => {
                const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CustomerDeleteDialogComponent);
                dialogRef.componentInstance.customer = data;
                dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
                    result => this.synchronize()
                );
            }
        );
    }
```

And the view code has changed to:

```
<button mat-icon-button color="accent" (click)="delete2(item)">
                    <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
                  </button>
```

And the delete confirmation dialog component is:

```
export class CustomerDeleteDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    customer: Customer;

    constructor(private customerService: CustomerService,
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CustomerDeleteDialogComponent>) { }

    delete2(): void {
        this.customerService.delete2(this.customer.id);
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (!this.customer) {}
        this.customer = { id: undefined, name: '', address: '', date: undefined };
    }
```

Being its view the next:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-icon color="warn">warning</mat-icon> <h3>Confirm: Delete Customer. Are you sure?</h3>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close cdkFocusInitial color="primary">Cancel</button>
    <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="true"  (click)="delete2()">Ok. Delete</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Finally, the readObservable() method from the Customer Service is:

```
readObservable(id: string): Observable<Customer> {
        return this.httpService.get(CustomerService.END_POINT + '/' + id);
    }
```

Now, the problem is: **when I choose to delete a customer**, it shows me the dialog, but when I click on OK (delete), **the customer persists**, although i get the snack bar of "success" launched for the method delete2() in the Customer Service.
Anyway, I think the problem can be related to the readObservable(). In addition, now I don't get error in the console.

Comment: first of all (click)="delete(item.id)" should be (click)="delete2(item.id)"

Answer (score 0):

```
item.id
```

This is an undefined variable. Are you sure, that your item has that "id" property? As I see you create the `item` object, but it has nothing meaningful in it yet.